# How does heat conduction differ from convection?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

How does heat conduction differ from convection?

Comment: Have you looked at the corresponding Wikipedia articles. What about this confuses you? Roughly speaking, convection means material motion, conduction is collisions.

Comment: Also, convection is a macro-scale phenomenon (bulk movement of fluid), whereas conduction is an atomic-scale phenomenon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP shows no research-efforts.

Comment: @user36790 Please stop abusing the close vote system. "No research effort" **is not** a reason to close.

Comment: @ChrisWhite: So, do you think OP shewed sufficient research effort?

Comment: @user36790 Sufficient effort to be upvoted? No. But sufficient effort to not be closed for that reason alone? Certainly yes, since there is no minimum amount of research effort.

Comment: @ChrisWhite: `there is no minimum amount of research effort`- now, from what perspective is my reasoning contrary to this?